# Removing MongoDB from Ubuntu

Tags: apt, mongodb, ubuntu-12.10

I recently started to mess with setting up ReplicaSets.  After some testing and playing, I was wanting to remove MongoDB and all settings, and start with a fresh install on all systems to get it set-up for production mode.  I assumed `sudo apt-get --purge remove mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-dev mongodb-10gen` followed by `sudo apt-get autoremove` would take care and I could just start again with install.  The problem is, when I do the fresh install, start up the Mongo Shell, it automatically starts me back up as if I was in my development mode ReplicaSets?  I have removed my .confs and mongodb directory from /var/lib/ but that still does not take care of it.  During the install, I get the prompt `(Reading database ... 76829 files and directories currently installed.)`  Where are these?  I do a `sudo dpkg -L mongodb-10gen` and get that it is not installed?

Any advice to help me avoid a complete Ubuntu re-install would be very helpful.  Thanks in advance for any guidance given!

Nathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the mongodb.conf file and see what dbpath is set for and then remove the db files.

Comment: Removed those files, re-installed Mongo, got this message when trying to enter the shell - `Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:91`

Comment: Is mongo up and running?

Comment: Yeah, it is running.  And working now, oddly enough.  Tried to enter the shell again after looking at that `mongo.js` file and everything is good.  Thanks!

Comment: May have been initializing/starting.